shub deploy returns auth error when pushin image to registry
when doing shub deploy I'm getting the following error:
Error failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token

The error arises when shub is trying to push the image to the registry.
I have tried the following with no success:

log out and then log in with shub
using the --reauth param
log out and then log in to Docker

Any hint will be much appreciated

You mention Docker. Could this be an issue with your Docker image? Does it work if you use shub deploy with a Scrapy Cloud project that does not use Docker?

thanks shub deploy works fine for projects that do not use Docker. As mentioned before the step that fails is when pushin the image to the registry (shub image push. It also fails for the sample project, so my guess is that there is an auth issue but cannot understand what permission might be missing
